# How to reach the upper platform on the area where an El Gigante is fought for the second time?

Tags: resident-evil-4-2005

[image: screenshot]

[image: map]

Shooting down the boulder almost seems to provide a pathway, but no context-sensitive prompt appears:

[image: screenshot]

---

To clarify, there indeed are several El Gigantes in the game.